# Getting FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory when trying to install forever running module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Getting FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: 0x8daaa0 node::Abort() [npm] when trying to install forever running module in mediatemple in nodejs project.

Please let me know how to solve it, as the current solutions suggested online are not helping.